# selected SIGNAL from QwtPlotPicker seems to be sending 3 times

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I have a `QwtPlot` and I need to select a point by clicking on it.

I'm using the `QwtPickerClickPointMachine` and the `QwtPlotPicker` classes to do so:

```
QwtPickerClickPointMachine picker_m = new QwtPickerClickPointMachine();
QwtPlotPicker d_picker = new QwtPlotPicker(QwtPlot::xBottom, QwtPlot::yLeft,
                                           QwtPlotPicker::CrossRubberBand, QwtPicker::AlwaysOn,
                                           dataPlot->canvas()); // dataPlot == QwtPlot
d_picker->setStateMachine(picker_m);
connect(d_picker, SIGNAL(selected(QPointF)), this, SLOT(test(QPointF)));
```

On my test function I am just printing an output:

```
void MyClass::test(QPointF point)
{
    qDebug() << "test";
}
```

But the problem is that when I click on the `QwtPlot` the output is:

```
test
test
test
```

It seems to be calling three times. I don't have any idea why this is happening. Can someone give me an explanation please?

Comment: Did you connect the signal more than 1 time? You will get 3 signals if you connected 3 times.. if not could it be that you have more than one QwtPlotPicker created?

Comment: Or maybe you're calling 3 times the function in which mentioned code is implemented. Try adding _Qt::UniqueConnection_ flag as 5th argument of function _connect_ . You can find more here [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm. Actually, I have just one connection and one `QwtPlotPicker` and both are created in the constructor. But the problem is that I am creating multiple objects of this class, and this is causing the problem. It was my mistake, I just need one object of this class. @drescherjm your tip helped me to find the problem. Thanks @Andre, I will read about it (I didn't know about this flag).

Comment: @Andre, Thanks! I didn't know about `Qt::UniqueConnection` even though I have used Qt for 8+ years at the day job..